# synthetic convertible dynamics

Tags: convertible-bond, synthetic

[A synthetic convertible bond can be created by combining a non-convertible bond with a long dated call option or warrant of the same issuer.](https://www.calamos.com/~/media/documents/market-insights/2015/08/ConvertibleSecurities_18080_0615.pdf)

Are there any papers which studies the dynamics of synthetic convertibles? I'm particularly interested in how the choice of maturity and strike with the call option and duration/yield of the bond affects dynamics.